# "Templates with transforms requires capabilities: CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND" During Control Tower Customization deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, aws-control-tower

I am doing some Stackset Deployment through AWS Control Tower Customizations. Following the latest guide  [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/solutions-reference/customizations-for-aws-control-tower/latest/customizations-for-aws-control-tower-developer-guide.pdf). I am doing this for ease of deployment to multiple regions for a DevOps setup.

For one of my lambda templates, I ran into the `Templates with transforms requires capabilities: CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND` error.

From looking around, it looks like this issue is usually resolved by adding a capabilities flag during AWS CLI deployment. However, this is not the case for Control Tower Customizations since the template file is controlled by a `manifest.yml` file ( which doesn't seem to have a documented way to resolve this at moment)

Is there a way to resolve this problem?